# Typescript: define types for list of keys

Tags: typescript

I have a list of channels like:

```
type Channels = 'Channel1' | 'Channel2' | ....
```

and each channel has its own type, so I am using this code:

```
type BaseTypes = {[key in Channels]: object};
interface ChannelTypes extends BaseTypes {
    Channel1: {/* define required data*/},
    Channel2: {/* define required data*/},
}
```

I want to find a way when I add a value to channels to force me to update `ChannelTypes`, and reject any key in `ChannelTypes` not defined in `Channels`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mapped types and lookup types. First define type with list of channels as you did:

```
type Channels = 'Channel1' | 'Channel2';
```

Next define type which maps channel type to its data, for example:

```
type ChannelToData = {
  Channel1: string;
  Channel2: number;
};
```

And finally define type:

```
type ChannelTypes = {
    [Channel in Channels]: ChannelToData[Channel];
};
```

With this approach, if you add new type to union `Channels`, TypeScript forces you to define specific data type for it in type `ChannelToData`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFgQwHZIgGwM5QLxQOTzKpoCMeUAPvoSugEx4DcAsAFBuiSyK1oAqAewAiCYAhxQA3myjci6EgC4oGYACcAlkgDmLVrJrE6ypAFcAtgCMIavQF89HcNEPo%20zrLmn7ZUANquaFBacrwYALrKgYIiYgE8xOH2jEA)